# How to render <> using [innerhtml] in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been trying to render a simple string using **[innerHtml]** but I keep failing. Basically my issue is when I use <>. For example if my string is:

```
someText = "abc <1231> color";
```

I can render

> abc <1231> color

but if my string is: "abc <comment1 color" I can only render

> abc color

How can I render my string using **[innerHtml]**?

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-udpfu6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 solutions

1. Using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.
2. Instead of using `<>` on `someText, you can use` <>`to show`<`&`>` letters.

```
someText = "abc &lt;1234&gt; color";
```

Comment: well basically those <> are coming from the backEnd and your solution will need to be a regex and go through the entire string to find them. It's not me just replace them by hand

Comment: You can use `someText.replaceAll("<", "&lt;")` to replace all letters.

Comment: or you can use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` and this problem won't happen.

Comment: I like your innerText solution better. Thank you bro!

Comment: I just did :). Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to insert generic text, not actual HTML, you should use the following syntax:

```
<div>{{someText}}</div>
```

If it is important for you to use [innerHTML] for any reason, you could use `someText = 'abc <1231> color'.replace(/</g, '&lt;')` to strip all your HTML tags and thus resolve your issue.
You can then NOT use any HTML in your element.

To allow specific HTML elements, you could use something like this:

```
const someText = '<b>Bold Text <123></b>'.replace(/<((b|i|u|strong|a)\s|>)/g, '&lt;$1';
```

Anyway, it is highly unsafe to insert user generated HTML content into your components.
You can see [this documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#description) to see, why.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add a bit of caution here, because there are a few concerns with the two earlier answer submissions.

First off, I would avoid using `innerText` or `innerHTML` completely if you're just trying to display generic text data. Angular has built in [data-binding](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax) for that very reason and I'd recommend using that. As was mentioned in the first part of @nrausch example.

Secondly, If for some reason your ultimate goal is to display HTML via the `innerHTML` property to the user, the correct approach is to sanitize the HTML using Angular's built in [DOMSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml)

Here is an example of how to use the DomSanitizer:

First create a sanitization pipe:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Second use the pipe in your components HTML:

```
<div><strong>Binding Example:</strong> {{ name }}</div>

<div [innerHtml]="myHTML | safeHtml"></div>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-domsanitizer-6uqpof?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that shows you both methods.